# How can I control the internet sharing speed in my network?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, bandwidth, throttling

I want to share my Internet connection with my neighbors and control the speed I share with them. Is it possible? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is software out there that can be used for this purpose, the same type of software a lot of internet cafe's use to keep certain groups from over-utilizing a connection - most of these cost money. If your router can support it, you can also use QoS to specify certain IP ranges are throttled (you would set all your computers up in static outside the range and then DHCP the range you want QoS on so anything else that connects follows the bandwidth rules you specify).

Comment: @MaQleod:I don't have a router at the moment.Would the software still work?

Comment: if you don't have a router, how are you planning on sharing a connection? Knowing how your network will be set up is the first step in deriving a solution that will work.

Comment: I own a wired broadband connection

Comment: What does that mean? a modem? What is the device that you have?

Comment: I have a dsl connection

Comment: If you don't have wireless capability, you need to run at least one cable to your neighbor.  http://superuser.com/questions/143024/win-7-share-internet-connection-via-ethernet-and-wifi will show you how to use your computer to share a connection without a router, but honestly, a router will save you a lot of trouble.